# Dynamically creating two objects and assigning one to the other

Tags: c++

I've tried reading through the section on dynamic allocation of objects but I'm still really lost. I'm trying to have two classes (person and car) which the user can create up to 100 objects of each. Then I want the user to be able to assign a car to a specific person. I understand the basics of dynamic allocation and pointers but I don't get how the user would be able to create and assign two of these objects together. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any tries so far? Did you have any problems with some particular design? Can you use/have you tried containers like `std::vector`? Seems like a classic example from most c++ books of "**is-a**" and "**has-a**" relations

Comment: I have just the basic format of two classes but I'm stuck from there...I'm confused by the idea of a user entering the value for a two different objects and assigning one to the other. I will look into the "has-a" relations you mentioned to see if I can better understand, thanks

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a `class Person` which has a `class Car`. Probably one person can have more than one car and probably one car can be owned by more than one person. You have to store all the `Person` and `Car` objects somewhere (like `std::vector`) and each of those objects should have means of reaching the other (like pointers). You can make a menu where the user is prompted to input a new person, a new car or assign one to another (a menu with options, reading user input and creating/assigning objects).

Comment: Thank you Rogus, you have given me a good direction to go in. I will see what I can do with it!